# Android SimpleCursorAdapter No such column Id

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, illegalargumentexception

I have a Listview that I want to populate with information from my SQLite database with and this seemed like the most practical solution.
In my debugger it says it's caused by:

> IllegalArgumentException No such column. Id does not exist

This is the java file I'm trying to populate it with:

```
    data        = new MyData(this);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                                this,
                                R.layout.list, 
                                data.selectData(), 
                                new String[] {
                                    "name",
                                    "title"
                                },
                                new int[] {
                                    R.id.name,
                                    R.id.title
                                }
    );
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

R.layout.list xml file:

```
<LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="8dip"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

public Cursor selectData() {

    return db.query("tbl_mydata", new String[] {"name", "abb" }, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: does your database get created???

Comment: Yep. Exported to an sql client and it shows :)

Answer (score 5):

You are not including **`_id`** in your column list for the query you do in **getSpinnerData()**.

FYI,

You must be extending [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) which demand **`_id`** column.

**`_id`** is used only in CursorAdapter to determine which column is id. You can override this behavior in CursorAdapter or add alias in query to id.

Comment: @Hiral thanx, FYI,i have also faced the same problem so i know it.

Comment: @poppoppop just a suggestion, as per StackOverflow FAQ, you should accept answer whenever you find it useful. Anyway cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleCursorAdapter` always need a _id field .

Your database contains table without id column or id with other column name . so uninstall app . and edit CREATE statement as :

```
  "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contact_data( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  something ,............ )
```

Answer (score 0):

It means either column name "name" or "data" does not exist in your database table.
Can you publish the table schema? Are these column names available?

Answer (score 0):

Actually declaring the _id as suggested above will work "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT", but if you don't need _id to be unique over the life of the table, you can omit the AUTOINCREMENT keyword, as the "PRIMARY KEY" will also autoincrement, but is logically equivalently to (max(_id)+1), which guarantees uniqueness which is really what you want when using the CursorAdapter.